# add data to many tables from form

Tags: java, forms, playframework

I use playframework with hibernate to controle my data.
I have 2 table with relations many to many. 
Is exist a way to get new data from form and update 2 tables at the same time?
Like this

```
form(T.class).bindFromRequest().get();
```